# No muestra el valor de un nodo XMl

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Estoy leyendo un xml donde necesito el código del mensaje recibido, para esto hice en una parte del código esto:

```
 string responseValue;
  while (reader.Read())
    {
     if (reader.Name == "ns2:Response")
        {
          if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
           {
              responseValue = reader.Value;
            }
         }
    }
```

cuando coloco un punto de interrupción en el `if`; no muestra ningún valor. Por qué puede suceder esto??

El xml esta así (o la parte donde quiero obtener el valor):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-14799">
  <ns2:SendInvoice xmlns:ns2="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/DocumentSendTo" xmlns:ns4="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/VersionRequest">
      <ns2:Response>200</ns2:Response>
      <ns2:Comments>Ejemplar recibido exitosamente pasará a verificación. </ns2:Comments>
  </ns2:SendInvoice>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: como obienes ese mensaje soap? porque no se supone que debas parsear ningun xml, si creadte un proxy al servicio wcf deberias obtener los datos directo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si se creo un proxy pero no se como obtener los datos directo, asi que estoy parseando el xml, si tienes un ejemplo de obtener los datos directamente seria excelente!!!

Comment: debes instanciar la clase que crea el "service reference" invocando el metodo del servicio para obtener los datos, no se deberia acceder al soap

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya entendí lo que te refieres, lo que pasa es que hay veces que el servicio (error del servidor) no responde y no me manda nada de response al trace, debo de leer el ultimo trace y mirar que halla algun valor o no este el response, y cual valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlReader` es un lector secuencial, lee un nodo a la vez, es decir cuando encuentras `ns2:Response` no sabe todavía que hay más data dentro del elemento, tienes que seguir leyendo, algo así:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Name == "ns2:Response")
    {
        while (reader.Read() && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
            {
                responseValue = reader.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```